# Properly applying scope in a custom directive to a child element in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-directive

So I have this custom directive:

```
function numberPickerDirective() {
        return {
            template: template,
            replace: 'true',
            restrict: "E",
            scope: {
                id: "@",
                name: "@",
                model: "=",
                value: "@",
                min: "@"
            },

        }
    }
```

And my template looks like this:

```
<div class="number-picker">

    <input id="{{id}}" name="{{name}}" ng-model="{{model}}"
        ng-value="{{value}}" value="{{value}}" min="{{min}}" required
        type="number" />

    <div class="number__controls">
        <button class="number__control-btn up-icon">
            <svg viewBox="0 2 10 5" width="10" height="5" fill-rule="evenodd">
                <path d="M10 5L5 0 0 5z"></path>
            </svg>
        </button>

        <button class="number__control-btn down-icon">
            <svg viewBox="0 2 10 5" width="10" height="5" fill-rule="evenodd">
                <path d="M10 0L5 5 0 0z"></path>
            </svg>
        </button>
    </div>
</div>
```

In my view, I'm applying the directive with:

```
<number-picker 
    id="inteval"
    name="SizeSec"
    ng-model="m.SizeSec"
    value="30"
    min="1"
    required
    type="number"
    />
```

The issue is that all of my scope variables are being applied to the top level div, when I want them to be applied to the input tag. Can anyone explain why this is happening and how to fix it?

Comment: I didn't understand your question, would you mind to rephrase it please?

Comment: When I inspect my element when it's rendered it ends up as: <div id='foo' name='foobar' etc..> <input /> </div> instead of <div> <input id='foo' name='foobar' etc...> </div> all of the parameters are getting applied to the wrong element for some reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's probably because you use `replace: true`. In this case, angularjs needs to apply your attributes somewhere, just put `replace: false` to fix it. Note that this does not really matter, at the end of the day, the attribute are correctly applied to the "input".

Moreover, it's probably best to use the `false` value as Angular 2+ does not allow you to replace the directive by its content, so it would help you migrate to Angular 2+ more easily.

Besides, you'll want to

- Replace `{{ model }}` by `model` or it won't work.
- Use `ng-value` instead of `value` to avoid a warning in the Chrome developer toolbar.

Note that I tested it with ng 1.7.2 and it works as expected.

[image]

See [this plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/hinGe9yEW2oMePPe3Evi?p=info).

Comment: Aha! I think it was the model change that fixed it. But now it's both the div and the input?

Comment: What do you mean? If you stick with `replace: true`, the "my-directive" tag disappears, so angularjs applies your attributes to the first child, so your `div`. That's why I recommend you to use `replace: false` to ensure that attributes are applied to "my-directive" and not the first element. Moreover, it's cleaner and more aligned with the "web components" style. Btw, I added a plunker to my response for you to see.

Comment: Ahh I was passing 'false' instead of false. Thanks for your help!